# Top Header Img Left on Computers & Center on phones & Tablets

Tags: image, css, responsive

Today I added a colored background table with a animated gif in the table to the top of some software that I'm editing.  With proper css, how can I get the image to always be Left on computer screens, and Centered on phones & tablets?  Below is how I have the current HTML.  Thanks!  :--)

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #663399;">
        <div><img src="Image URL" alt="Animated Gif"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see any code in your question...

Comment: S O Isn't showing the code, but when I click on Edit, I see it.  It's a basic table code with style= css, and <div></div> outside of the image code url.  I need to get off the computer for the rest of the night.  :--)

Comment: can you write separate CSS ? or only inline css ?

Comment: Now the Code is showing.  I could put css in a (.css) file, put it in between <script>css here</script>.  :--)

Comment: Thanks!  Does that run on All computer & mobile browsers?!  :--)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.img-wraper {
   text-align: left; 
}
.img-wraper img {
  display: inline-block; 
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .img-wraper {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #663399;">
        <div class="img-wraper"><img src="Image URL" alt="Animated Gif"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```